# How to integrate SQL Server Express with VS C# Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, integration, visual-studio-express, sql-server-2008-express

I have just installed VS C# Express 2008 which includes SQL Server Express 2008. It all went ok and I can see VS C# and SQL Server in the list of installed products.

When I start VS C# it looks fine but in the DB Explorer / Data Connection context menu the option 'Create new SQL Server Database' is disabled.

I have uninstalled all VS products and reinstalled but the problem remains. Do I need to do anything else?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC# seems to insist on using attached database files (*.mdf). This will keep your database local to your project rather than cluttering your SQL Server Express with databases.

You can create your database with the **Add Connection...** dialog, by choosing the **Microsoft SQL Server Database File** option. The database will reside in a file of your choosing. It works pretty well for any typical 'express' kind of project.

Note: If you use the SQL Management Studio Express to create a database in your SQLEXPRESS instance, you can still connect to it programatically by using the appropriate connection string.

Comment: Thanks Tor. That works. Have now idea what that means though. Is this the right way to develop a multi-user project? There will be more questions.... !

Comment: Actually, I must say I think this sucks somewhat. I get a distinct feeling MS have crippled the express edition to nudge people towards paying for the full VS.

Answer (score 0):

I would download [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) and instead create your database in that.

Comment: That won't help him, because VC# insists on working with attached database files. The said dialog won't let him connect to the database from VC#.

Comment: If he's using the database directly instead of the drag-drop stuff that's good for demos and not much else then that will work fine.